# UITableView shadow top?

Tags: ios, uitableview, gradient, layer, cells

I know there have been many questions on this before however none seem to work in my scenario. Pretty much I am trying to make the top maybe 10 points below the top of the frame of my tableview somewhat darker so have a nicer effect than just the cells scrolling off the frame.

Pretty much I need to accomplish an effect where the alpha starts at 0 and ends at 1 of a gray color which is 10 points high. This way there is some sort of subtle area before the top of the frame so that it doesn't look like the cells are just moving out of the frame.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a navigation controller, why not just set it's shadow on it's layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a shadow to the navigationBar layer, assuming you are using one.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.0f);
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
```

If you are not using a navigation controller, then you can apply this same type of shadow to a UIView's layer.

Comment: I am not using one but I will try this!

Comment: Then you can add a `UIView` and apply the same shadow logic as shown above to that view.

Comment: The only thing I am confused about is the offset value and the radius. If I say want the shadow to be the width of the tableview and 10 points high from the top of the tableview, how would I do that? Also what exactly is the shadowRadius?

Comment: You would make your "ShadowView" the entire width of the tableView. The shadow radius will affect the size of the shadow.  The larger the radius the bigger the shadow.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW85